# Data on (non-sexual) child abuse

Tags: data-request

I am looking for data on child abuse, broken down by sex of the victim and, if possible, sex of the perpetrator and relation to the victim. Age of child would be useful, too.

There is a lot of data on child sexual abuse, but I can only find very brief summary statistics on non-sexual child abuse.

I may not be searching in the right way or the right places, so I'd be happy for any and all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curious to what you are searching and where? Searching Google for "non sexual child abuse statistics open data" gave me multiple resources on first page of SERPS. You're going to have to pick through these, but they all separate sexual/non-sexual in one form or another.
[Childstats.gov](http://www.childstats.gov/index.asp)
[Kids Count](http://www.aecf.org/work/kids-count/)
[Child Abuse Statistics, Research, and Resources - If you use this one make sure and double check the legitimacy of the site. Looks ok from brief glance, but I would not take that chance doing any real work with this data prior to confirming](http://www.jimhopper.com/abstats/)
[Abuse/Bullying - Alberta Gov](http://www.humanservices.alberta.ca/abuse-bullying/17395.html)
[UK Child Abuse Statistics](https://www.nspcc.org.uk/services-and-resources/research-and-resources/statistics/)
[Child Abuse Statistics - Iowa](https://dhs.iowa.gov/reports/child-abuse-statistics)